# What’s wrong with my code its returning “I’M A Little Tea Pot” instead of “I’m A Little Tea Pot’?

Tags: javascript, regex, function

```
function titleCase(str) {
  let a = str.toLowerCase();
  let b = /\b[a-z]/g;
  return a.replace(b, b => b.toUpperCase());
}
console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

Comment: must mean that `\b` matches `'`

Comment: `My name is O'Leary and I like s'mores`